# Lifetime of JavaScript objects created inside functions

Tags: javascript, scope, javascript-objects

Assume that I have an HTML list `<ul>` and I add `<li>` items dynamically with JS. So the list becomes like this:

```html
<ul id="parent">
  <li> //container
  Some text <button>Delete</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here, the `<button>` is used to delete the `<li>` using JS. I created a class with a `delete` method to delete the `<li>` when the button is clicked:

```js
class MyObj {
  constructor(parent, container) {
    this.parent = parent;
    this.container = container;
  }

  delete() {
    this.parent.removeChild(this.container);
  }
}
```

And this is the function that is used to create `<li>` elements:

```js
function create() {
  let container = document.createElement('li');
  let deleteContainerBtn = document.createElement('button');

  container.innerHTML = "Sometext";
  container.appendChild(deleteContainerBtn);
  parent.appendChild(container);

  const obj = new MyObj(parent, container, deleteContainerBtn);
  
  deleteContainerBtn.onclick = function() {
    obj.delete()
  };
};
```

This works fine (I add `<li>` containers with function `create` as many times as I want and they can be deleted when I click their <kbd>Delete</kbd> buttons). How?
When function `create` is done executing, isn’t `obj` supposed to be deleted? How does it perform the `delete` method if it is deleted?

Comment: `function() { obj.delete() }` is a _closure_ that closes over `obj`. Since it references it internally, `obj` can never get garbage collected, unless the closure itself is not referenced by anything. Aside: prefer [`addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) over `.onclick`.

Comment: simply speaking, if you can refer to it, it would be alive. (if you're worry about lifetime issue)